# [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]] is not working only on iPad with iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

The statement:

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

has `no effect only on iPad especially with iOS8 with my existing App only`. Just for a shake of test I have created a new Test App just to pin point the problem but `it works`. I have created a `UIViewController` class like this:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [aTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:aTableView];
}

@end
```

and push ist with the following statement:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[TestViewController new] animated:YES];
```

Pushing from the new Test App results like this (as I want):

[image]

but from my existing App (the real App where I have to implement) result like this:

[image]

**Clearing the background color works perfectly under iOS7 iPhone and iPad even with iOS 8 iPhone. I have tried to find UIAppearance Proxy implementation that can influence the appearance but there isn't any.**

I have already tried s**everal SO proposals** including `setting the backgroundView to nil` and `they haven't helped`.

Why it is working with new Test App and why it is not working with my Existing App? Anything to do with `UINavigationController`?

**NB:** Please don't mark as a duplicate because here the question is totally or slightly different than the existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

This is cell's color. So you have to change your cell's color. For more info see

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: I have already tried your proposal and I have just tried again too but there is no change. Please note the above mentioned (my code) works with one App and not working with another. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;
```

Try the above code